# Setting ViewController's managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using CoreData and I set the `NSManagedObjectContext` in `AppDelegate` file.

I need to get that managedObjectContext in a ViewController which is many levels deep in the naviagation tree. Obviously, I do not want to pass it along all the init methods.

I have tried `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];` but I get this error "**No known instance method for selector 'managedObjectContext'**"

Can someone guide me on how to get the managedObjectContext from `AppDelegate` to this `ViewContoller`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you need to create a property in your `AppDelegate.h` like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; // or strong if you ARC instead of retain
```

Using `readonly` prevent you to modify the context externally.

In `AppDelegate.m` synthesize it like:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

Always within the `AppDelegate.m` override the getter method like

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{    
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) return managedObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {

        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

Once done you have a `managedObjectContext` property which can be accessed anywhere with

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

A more cool approach could be to create a class method in your `AppDelegate.h` like the following:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
```

Then in `AppDelegate.m` do like the following:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Now, anywhere, before having imported your `AppDelegate` header (`#import "AppDelegate.h"`), you can do:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

### **Note**

Using such an approach causes your application to become rigid. To overcome this problem I suggest you to read about [passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/01/07/passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone/) by Marcus Zarra.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The link you shared is great... but it doesn't work with storyboard. How do we setup the first view controller to have a reference to the managed object context?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the global sharedApplication variable into your own app's `AppDelegate` class. Here's an example:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];            
// Now you can access appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Note: you'll need to `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in the .m file where you use this code.